# Python multiprocessing's Pool constants

Tags: python, multiprocessing, constants, pool

I'm beginner with the multiprocessing module in python and I want to use concurrent execution ONLY for my ***def func***. Moreover I'm using some constants in my code and I have problem with them.
The code is (python 3.6.8):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

FIRST_COUNT=10
print("Enter your path")
PATH=input()

some_list=[]
for i in range(10000):
    some_list.append(i)  


def func(some_list):
    .....


if __name__ == "__main__":
chunks = [some_list[i::4] for i in range(4)]
pool = Pool(processes=4)

pool.map(func,chunks)
```

When I try to start this programm, I see the message Enter your path 5 times and 5 times I need to input my path. i.e this code execute 1 + 4(for each processes) times.

I want to use FIRST_COUNT, PATH and some_list like a constants, and use multiprocesseing only for **func**. How can i do this. Please, help me.

Comment: Read [executing-modules-as-scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)

Comment: put other code in function and execute it in `__main__` - or put it directly in `__main__` - this way it will be executed only once.

Comment: better send `FIRST_COUNT` and `PATH` to `func` as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put code inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` to execute it only once

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    FIRST_COUNT = 10
    PATH = input("Enter your path: ")

    some_list = list(range(10000))
    #some_list = []
    #for i in range(10000):
    #    some_list.append(i)  

    chunks = [some_list[i::4] for i in range(4)]
    pool = Pool(processes=4)

    results = pool.map(func, chunks)

    print(results)
```

If you want to use `FIRST_COUNT`, `PATH` then better send it to `func` as arguments.

You will have to create tuples with `FIRST_COUNT`, `PATH` in `chunks`

```
chunks = [(FIRST_COUNT, PATH, some_list[i::4]) for i in range(4)]
```

and function will have to get it as tuple and unpack it

```
def func(args):
    first_count, paht, some_list = args
```

---

Working example

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(args):
    first_count, path, some_list = args

    result = sum(some_list)

    print(first_count, path, result)

    return result 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FIRST_COUNT = 10
    PATH = input("Enter your path: ")

    some_list = list(range(10000))
    #some_list = []
    #for i in range(10000):
    #    some_list.append(i)  

    chunks = [(FIRST_COUNT, PATH, some_list[i::4]) for i in range(4)]
    pool = Pool(processes=4)

    all_results = pool.map(func, chunks)

    print('all results:', all_results)
```

---

**EDIT:** You can also use `starmap()` instead of `map()`

```
    all_results = pool.starmap(func, chunks)
```

and then you can use (without unpacking arguments)

```
def func(first_count, path, some_list):
```